# UISplitViewController programatically - specific settings Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uisplitviewcontroller

We use `UISplitViewController` programatically, without using Storyboard. We want to reach a specific behavior of the split view controller and we fail to do that, even though we have already tried various settings combinations. What we want is following: For iPhones we want the master controller (in our case table) to be displayed first, with transitions to detail controllers, so it would behave like a regular Navigation controller. For iPads portrait, we want THE SAME behavior as for iPhones and for landscape, we want both, master and detail controllers visible side by side. Closest we got was with following split view controller's settings:

- `preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible`
- `func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
      return true
  }`

With such settings, everything works as we want, EXCEPT: on iPad portrait, both, master and detail controllers are visible side by side but we want that behavior only for lanscape mode. For iPad portrait, we want it to behave exactly the same as for iPhones, so only master would be displayed first (full screen) with transitions to detail and back.